# How do I fix: Eclipse Builder Error - Drools

Tags: drools

I have Eclipse 2020-03 with Maven and Drools (via install new software). My first project follows
[RedHat 7.5 Using Java to run DRLs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.1/html/designing_a_decision_service_using_drl_rules/drl-rules-other-con)

and I am getting builder error:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Drools Builder' on project 'Drools_1'.
org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils

I have d/l the math3 JAR, added it to my build path.

Any ideas about the Drools Builder? It's one of the builders in the project > Properties > Builders

Comment: Have you tried following the instruction to setup the project as a Maven build? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.1/html/designing_a_decision_service_using_drl_rules/drl-rules-other-con#drl-rules-maven-create-proc_execute-rules If so, the build via the command line `mvn clean verify` performs successfully? Because in that case you might have missed some necessary Eclipse/Drools tools setup steps.

Comment: I do have the project "mavenized". Run as > Maven clean, > Maven install and > Maven build <compile:compile> run to success. I get the same Clean / Build error in my Eclipse+Drools and in my Red Hat CodeReady Studio + Drools. It appears to be a Builder error.